# What is the easiest way to summarize/aggregate/cluster point features?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, clustering, aggregate-points

I have a file with more than 2000 point features and I want to summarize them. However the points that interest me the most, are the ones with the fewest neighbours. The point features which appear in groups are less interesting and therefore should be summarized to simplify my further analysis. It would be best to aggregate them solely on the attribute of the distance between each other, because they have no other attributes. Any ideas? See images below.

[image]

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking. It sounds like you want to do the summary based entirely on proximity to other points. Have you tried using the "Near" tool in Analysis->Proximity?

Comment: Basically I want to cluster or summarize points that are close to eachother to single features.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to summarize the point features by using the "integrate" tool. It allows to specify a maximum range so features within this range will be summarized in their epicentre.

Comment: That looks very reasonable!

Comment: If you have long skinny cluster, e.g. points one foot apart along a road for 100 miles, is the result a single cluster, or does Integrate break it into smaller clusters?